# What does variable names beginning with _ mean?

Tags: c#, asp.net, syntax, variables, naming-conventions

When writing my first asp.net MVC application using C#, I see that there are some variables whose name start with an underscore character(_).

What does this mean? Is there any specific meaning for this?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

There's no language-defined meaning - it's just a convention some people use to distinguish instance variables from local variables. Other variations include m_foo (and s_foo or g_foo or static variables) or mFoo; alternatively some people like to prefix the local variables (and parameters) instead of the instance variables.

Personally I don't use prefixes like this, but it's a style choice. So long as everyone working on the same project is consistent, it's usually not much of an issue. I've seen some *horribly* inconsistent code though...

Comment: What's the difference between local variables and instance variables? Instance variable: A variable that it is bounded to the object itself (properties, attributes from the class). Local variable: A variable that it is typically used in a method or a constructor. More information: https://www.google.com/search?q=difference+between+local+and+instance+variables

Answer (score 36):

In general, this means private member fields.

Comment: More generally, for non-public instance fields (that includes protected and internal ones too).

Comment: Wherever you see underscore, you could interpret "this.". In other words, a shorthand. But be careful, in modern C#, underscore is also used to temporary keep results that we won´t use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards, so, the "old" use for "this." may be confusing nowadays

Comment: @zameb Right, but only if the variable name is just '_', on its own, not if it is a variable name starting with an underscore. Or did I miss something?

Comment: You're right Keith

Answer (score 14):

The underscore before a variable name `_val` is nothing more than a convention. In C#, it is used when defining the private member variable for a public property.

I'll add to what @[Steven Robbins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26507/steven-robbins) said:

```
private string _val;
public string Values
{
    get { return _val;}
    set {_val = value;}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A lot of people use them for property private variables (the variables that actually store the values for public properties).

Answer (score 2):

There is another advantage with starting an instance property with '*', it shows up first on Intellisense.

When creating a value/model/POCO class, I don't using '*'.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little old, but in case anyone ends up here I'll add to the answers here that if you are talking about MVC on .NET, also there is a naming convention on partial views also with their names starting with underscore.

This are naming conventions that you and your team can decide to follow or not, as long as all of you are aware of the decision. I use them also with non public fields like private or protected just to recognize them.

[Here's a little brief about it](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/omars/2004/02/05/c-coding-standards-for-private-member-variables/) if you want to read further.

Answer (score 1):

The use of an underscore for property private variables is very useful in avoiding situations where you may accidentally call the variable and not the property within the class itself. (Easily done with a simple lowercase intellisense input)

If you undertake some form of calculation or aggregation within the property get{} the last thing you want to do is miss this when your intention is to call the property in full.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen it used as a variable name for parameters which are not being used as a way to 'hide' them away from the rest of the function.

I can't say this is a good or bad thing but it was effective at indicating that the parameter was not to be used in the function.